# Como eu consigo clonar um registro de uma tabela usando stored procedure e pegando os campos dinamicamente?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dinâmico, clone

Eu tenho a necessidade de clonar um registro em uma tabela mas pegando os campos da forma como estão, o motivo é que alguém pode inserir ou retirar alguma coluna, então eu não sei quais colunas eu tenho na tabela naquele momento.

Eu criei um procedure para fazer isso, eu passo um ID, ele executa e me retorna o novo ID. Espero estar conseguindo me expressar e que alguém consiga me ajudar, segue abaixo um exemplo de procedure que eu criei.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spClonaPedido]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PedidoId int,
    @NovoId int output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @COLUNA VARCHAR(100), @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX), @CLOCAR VARCHAR(MAX);

    --- Inicializar a variavel
    SET @COLUNAS    = ''
    SET @NovoId     = ''
    SET @CLOCAR     = ''

    --sempre declare que o cursor é do tipo LOCAL FAST_FORWARD.
    --Local diz que é o scopo da execuçao e FAST_FORWARD significa que ele so vai pra frente.
    DECLARE CURCOLUNAS CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_CATALOG   = 'MeusPedidos'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME  = 'pedidos'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    OPEN CURCOLUNAS
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @COLUNAS = @COLUNAS + ', ' + @COLUNA
            FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA --- O into nesta linha
        END

        SET @COLUNAS= Right(@COLUNAS, len(@COLUNAS)-2)
        SET @CLOCAR = 'INSERT INTO Pedidos ('+@COLUNAS+') SELECT '+@COLUNAS+' FROM Pedidos WHERE PedidoId = '+@PedidoId

        EXEC(@CLOCAR)

        SET @NovoId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        RETURN  @NovoId
    CLOSE CURCOLUNAS;
    DEALLOCATE CURCOLUNAS;
END
```

Comment: Tá, e qual a sua dificuldade? Sua `procedure` já não funciona?

Comment: e se vc usar a sintaxe sem informar as colunas ? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Opa, a procedure não está funcionando, está dando erro na hora do insert. Mas o link que você recomendou é possível. A necessidade de fazer dessa forma como eu montei é que no momento em que essa procedure rodar algumas novas colunas podem surgir na tabela, daí eu pensei em selecionar todas as colunas e não usar o * para não ser barrado na validação. Mas eu agradeço pelo link.